# How do I tell what's preventing sleep on Ubuntu? My box won't sleep automatically!

Tags: suspend, power-management

Manually sleeping my Ubuntu desktop from a menu works fine.
I've set preferences to "Suspend when inactive" for "5 Minutes".
Yet the computer often does not sleep.

On Windows, I use `powercfg -requests` to see what the hold-up is.
On a Mac, I can use `pmset -g assertions` to see what's preventing sleep
([Source](https://lifehacker.com/5924010/how-to-find-out-whats-keeping-your-computer-from-going-to-sleep)).

I think maybe Chrome is preventing sleep, but I can't be sure.

Is there a Linux equivalent way to find out?
Can [powertop](https://01.org/powertop) be used this way?

```
14.04 LTS> gsettings list-recursively | grep plugins.power
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 120
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 120
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true


cat /etc/default/acpi-support | grep SUSPEND_METHODS

SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-pm dbus-hal pm-utils"
```

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running? On a recent one, with `systemd`, you can check the logs with `journalctl`. On older systems, without `systemd`, you might want to check `dmesg`and `/var/log/syslog` for messages that tell you what is going on. You could also check with `iotop` to see if something is active on your disk.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 in this case.  dmesg and syslog don't really give any clues.  It seems it could be a web browser related issue, but of course a web browser is always running.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide the output to `gsettings list-recursively  | grep plugins.power` and ping me @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby added gsettings output.

Comment: Do you only have this issue when the laptop is plugged in? Or an external monitor is?

Comment: I'm looking for a generic answer to diagnose the situation.
My specific box is a desktop (no laptop) with dual monitors, which are both in use always.  It is always plugged in.

Comment: Have you tried to suspend it form the command line ? With `powermanagement-interface` installed you can try `pmi action suspend` of `pm-suspend`. May need `sudo`. That could help you debug, as you don't have to wait for your PC to try and suspend on tits own.

Comment: "pmi action suspend" results in "Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files"

Comment: I am looking for an canonical answer to how one lists what services are blocking sleep, for general debugging now and into the future.

Comment: what shows this command ? --> cat /etc/default/acpi-support | grep SUSPEND_METHODS

Comment: Attached.  I'm looking for SLEEP BLOCKERS, not instructions on using sleep.

Comment: Does the PC have sucess in manual suspend ?

Comment: It is possible that the surface your mouse is on causes random mouse movements (mouse moves 1 pixel to either side).  Try putting your mouse upside down.

Comment: @Bryce - it appears that @kanehekili 's `systemd-inhibit` response is the correct answer? Could you please accept if so to help the community, or leave a response indicating why the answer is incomplete?

Answer (score 14):

You need to find the inhibitors, a.k.a. which processes are preventing your suspend:

```
systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
```

That will list the processes which do not "want to sleep"

Answer (score 2):

You have to set:

- System Settings > Power set to turn off after 10 minutes.
- System Settings > Brightness and Lock to turn off the screen after 10 minutes.

for both battery and "when plugged in":

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 300
```

you can also set:

org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
 `sleep-display-battery` to a value lower than the value of
 `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout`

Answer (score 0):

By using xfce desktop, clicking battery taskbar icon show them
[image]