# ubuntu 20.04 won't go idle

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I want my screen and/or the pc to go to sleep(or suspend) after x amount of time. Have enabled automatic suspend, blank screen after 1 minute, blank screen delay(inside the Privacy section), and it does nothing.
Searched the web for possible fixes and disabled the bluetooth as well(to prevent it from not going to idle). Disabled to mouse so that it won't "jiggle" - nothing happens. Is this supposed to work on a desktop pc(not a laptop)?

Seeing that most of the questions regarding this are related to "how do i disable suspend in ubuntu", my first reaction was wtf, why does everyone wants to turn this off?

I don't know how to debug this and certainly don't wanna go back to win 10 just b/c of this, so every hint or suggestion is welcome!

Comment: yes it already did, thx!

Answer (score 0):

found out that there was a program "inhibiting" gnome from going to sleep.

Used this answer - [How to find a program which is preventing sleeping?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071514/how-to-find-a-program-which-is-preventing-sleeping)