# Ubuntu 20.04 suspend does not work

Tags: 20.04, suspend, xps

I found a few related questions, but nothing for 20.04, and questions for 20.04 are about resuming after suspend, or suspend on lid close etc.

I recently updated my XPS 15 laptop from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and suspend is no longer working. Basically nothing happens when I close the lid or click on "suspend" in xfce4-session-input. The screen goes black, but the CPU and fans are still running. Same when I close the lid. When I press a key it asks for the user password.

Any tips on how to fix "sleep" on Ubuntu 20.04?

`cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` shows `[s2idle] deep`.

Thanks.

`inxi -F` output:

```
System:    Host: omer-XPS-15-9570 Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: i3 4.17.1
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 15 9570 v: N/A
           serial: <superuser/root required>
           Mobo: Dell model: 0D0T05 v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.8.1
           date: 02/01/2019
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 85.8 Wh condition: 88.2/97.0 Wh (91%)
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-8750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 9216 KiB
           Speed: 3961 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3989 2: 1119 3: 2903
           4: 2982 5: 901 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 9: 904 10: 3760 11: 3400 12: 3400
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] driver: N/A
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
           resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-25-generic
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath10k_pci
           IF: wlp59s0 state: up mac: 9c:b6:d0:c3:bb:65
           Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 51.82 GiB (10.9%)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KXG60ZNV512G NVMe 512GB size: 476.94 GiB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 51.82 GiB (11.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 31.0 C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:      Processes: 276 Uptime: N/A Memory: 15.28 GiB used: 856.2 MiB (5.5%) Shell: zsh
           inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case what solved it was updating my AMD GPU drivers.

Get .deb file from: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-10-2 (check exact version, in my case I had Ubuntu 20.04.4), install it with `sudo dpkg -i amdgpu-install_***.deb` then install latest drivers by running `amdgpu-install`.

I see you have Nvidia GPU but maybe it's a similar issue or maybe someone else having an AMD GPU sees this answer.

Comment: In my case the GPU-Driver seems to be the error. I own a Nvidia GeForce GTX 960. I used the X.ORG X server driver and it works with the nvidia-driver-470 driver. The nvidia-driver-510 causes a dark screen after wakeup

Comment: Firefox crashed with `|[0][GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate (t=308.292) |[1][GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate (t=3961.27)` using  nvidia-driver-470 driver. I do not know if this caused by the driver but I will try another one

Comment: Just want to mention I noticed that having 2 monitors connected to the PC also seems to cause issues even with the drivers I mentioned, when I only have one connected sleep/wakeup seems to be working fine.

Comment: I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia-driver-510 and the suspend bug is gone. I have got three monitors connected to my Nvidia GTX 960.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I swiched to 22.04

Comment: Update: It worked twice and now the bug is back again

Comment: I tried nvidia-driver-390 and my system could not boot after this. I do not know if this is related to the driver.

Answer (score 3):

So you did a "dist-upgrade" from 18 to 20. What are your power settings say?
It should look like this:

[[image: 1]]

"Laptop Lid" should be in "Suspend mode". The file */etc/systemd/logind.conf* should have not active entries (all entries start with **"#"**)

To confirm that your system is still able to sleep, open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

If that does not work, you seem to have an "inhibitor", some code that prevents your system to go to sleep.
Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226609/906933) on how to find out...

**Update**

In xfce you'll always see the the powermanager listed - this is ok and the standard. If this is the only line, there are no inhibitors that will interfere with the powermanagement.

**Update2**

After we discussed some missing information, it seems that your system can't sleep. As you tried "systemctl suspend" in vain, some driver must be the culprit.

Getting a decent answer would include a list of drivers you are using - add them to your question. Use

```
inxi -F
```

Comment: `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block` shows `xfce4-power-manager`. Now what?

Comment: Yeah, the power-manager is responsible for it. But what does the rest say? On my device it looks like this:
`xfce4-power-manager 1000 yourUserName 896 xfce4-power-man handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch xfce4-power-manager handles these events block`

Comment: It says `handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch`

Comment: I've updated my answer - you've got no problem concerning an inhibitor...  What happens if you enter in the terminal: `sudo systemctl suspend` ?

Comment: `sudo systemctl suspend` seems to work. At least the screen goes black. This laptop is pretty quiet when idle so can't tell for sure if it's suspended or just entered screen saving mode or something like that. When I close the lid or choose "suspend" in xfce4-session-manager the screen goes dark, but the laptop is actually running. Only way to understand is by checking battery usage after a few hours.

Comment: Here's an update: `sudo systemctl suspend` does not work. I realized this after an hour of video call making the laptop running hot. After `sudo systemctl suspend` the screen goes black and the computer becomes unresponsive to key presses, but the fan keeps running. Before updating to 20.04 (in 18.04), suspend would immediately stop everything, including the fans. So I think suspend is not working.

Comment: I'd setup my Ubuntu to 20.04 instead of "upgrading" it. It has never worked with my hardware... I know it's a pain to save everything and set it up again.

Comment: This is already installed from scratch. By "upgrade" I mean installing (from scratch) 20.04 to a 18.04 system. Sorry for confusing wording.

Comment: See my **Update2**. Copy the output of the command and paste it into your answer & format it. Using comments will render that unreadable

Comment: `inxi -F` output added

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04. The root cause was that I was using the `nouveau` driver instead of the proprietary one from NVIDIA. Once I switched to that suspend started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem for last month. until I found out that the package of 'linux-header-generic' did not installed properly. Somehow I found that the interface between kernel and component didn't installed.
So I install it:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

I install new kernel with this. And also after restart, in boot section I have to choose new kernel. Because old kernel exist too and Ubuntu choose it on default.