# Firefox stopped working with a BadAlloc X Window System Error on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, firefox, 21.10

My Firefox has stopped working out of the blue. I am on Ubuntu 21.10. Not sure if it was after a recent update. I have to assume it was. When I checked gnome menu editor, I see that the command in the .desktop file to run is `env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox %u` so I figure I run it in the terminal and see what the error is. The error is the following below

```
christopher@Chris-Gaming-Linux:~$ env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox %u
Gtk-Message: 18:41:59.114: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:41:59.115: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

(firefox:60465): Gdk-WARNING **: 18:42:01.096: The program 'firefox' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc'.
  (Details: serial 505 error_code 11 request_code 146 (unknown) minor_code 7)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Now interestingly, when I run Firefox in *safe mode*, it works! I have no idea why. I refreshed settings to default, and turned off all the extensions while in safe mode and reran it normally and I'm still getting that error. It's weird.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Also where do I file a bug?

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this exact error in a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 with the snap Firefox package. I switched to the apt package and it resolved the problem. However, I upgraded to 22.04, and the apt Firefox package is no longer available, and again faced this error.

I tried everything [vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) recommended without success. I noticed that the error complains of a problem with X Window System. When I checked Firefox's troubleshooting page in safe mode, I noticed that safe mode disables WebGL. I made a guess, **switched from the X.Org Nouveau display driver to the proprietary NVIDIA driver** nvidia-driver-510, restarted, and the error resolved.

I suspect a bug in the Nouveau driver.

How to switch from the X.Org Nouveau display driver to the proprietary NVIDIA driver:

1. list available drivers: `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`
2. find the **distro non-free recommended** one
3. install it: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-510`
4. restart

Comment: THANK you, this worked! Switching to nvidia-driver-470 solved the issue. The driver problem should be fixed ASAP, or update to 22.04 should be disabled for people with NVIDIA graphic cards, it's terrible to be locked out of all browsers.

Comment: I am having this same issue in the newly installed 22.04. I see that Tyler Moore's suggestion to switching to the nvidia driver worked. How can I go about this?

Comment: @jasperittle: Open the "Additional Drivers" program from the dash.

Answer (score 2):

the same problem with my GeForce 960.
I solved it by switching Nouveau to nvidia-driver-510.

Comment: I switched to Nvidia-driver-470 on Ubuntu 20.04 and it does work now. Now I got the [suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355817/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-does-not-work/1410380)

Comment: I switched to nvidia-driver-510 and the suspend bug is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This will be caused by an addon you are running, or by another issue in your current firefox profile.

Running Firefox in Safe mode, you could try some of the possibilities on the troubleshooting information.

Go there by going to "Help", "More troubleshooting" in the hamburger (≡) menu. On the right, you have some options:

- Refresh Firefox, which resets the user profile
- Troubleshooting Mode - this is what you are already doing by starting Firefox in safe mode `firefox -safe-mode`
- Clear startup cache

You could try the last option first, and if that fails, refresh firefox.

If you synchronize your profile through Firefox sync, you can use that to restore your bookmarks. Else you can save your current bookmarks first using "Manage bookmarks" (under "Bookmarks" in the menu, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) so you can restore them under the reset profile.